# Using seed-fu to seed data with associations (from csv)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, seed

I have a large csv file (must be spreadsheet-editable) of countries and regions.  Countries have_many regions.

The file has multiple lines for the same country, i.e:

```
USA, New York
USA, Pennsylvania
```

etc.

I'd like to use seed-fu to seed my database with this information.  I think I should use Writer to take the CSV file and generate a seed file, but I'm not sure how to do this while retaining the associations. Is there a standard method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this without Writer. My answer is:

- Process the file line by line, creating countries and regions as you go
- For each line, first try to create the country.  Then create the region using region_name and the country_id as the constraints to seed_fu's seed method.
- I avoid the inefficiency of calling seed multiple times on each country (which would be fine, but slow) by writing a wrapper to seed and using memoization.